# How to select data from the last four complete quarters of a timeseries with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Say I've got a dataframe with a datetime index which covers the last financial year and one day in the current financial year (starting on April 1) :

```
           Units
date
2016-01-01   8734   
2016-06-30   6120
2016-09-30   7346
2016-12-31   5925
2016-03-31   7542
2016-06-30   9916
2016-09-30   9547
2016-12-31   8063
2017-01-01   7000
2017-03-31   5672
2017-04-01   7856
```

I'd like to be able to select the data for the last complete four quarters - in this case ignoring the first and last rows.

I know I can do this with slicing, thus:

```
df["2016-04-01":"2017-03-31"]
```

What's the most elegant - pythonic - solution to filter the data according to the last four complete quarters programmatically?

Comment: I think you can do something like this ,  `df.date >="2016-04-01" &  df.date < "2017-03-31"`

Comment: Sorry, I had to tweak the question. I meant programmatically as I'd quite like to leave in a script that I don't want to tweak every time.

Comment: Do you mean to consider only the periods 01-01 to 03-31; 04-01 to 06-31; 07-01 to 09-31 and 10-01 to 12-31 as quarters or do you want varying 'quarters' according to your data? Unless you precisely define what you expect (or how long a 'quarter' is, which believe me, can vary!) this is an algorithm question, not a pandas or python question.

Comment: @vmg - Thanks for asking. Ideally, I'd like to select as you said. I actually created a text variable using df['Quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['Provision Date'], freq="Q-MAR").strftime("Q%q"), if that helps. (I'm getting a bit lost in the dateoffset stuff)

Answer (score 2):

You should first define your quarters. You can use `pd.period_range` for that with the correct freq :
example :

```
quarters = pd.period_range('2016Q1', '2017Q1', freq='Q-MAR')
```

This would give you a PeriodIndex on which you can change the frequency to get the dates you want with `asfreq` :

```
quarters.asfreq('D', 'E')
```

That would give you the PeriodIndex that you can use to slice your Index.

Here are more example in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help and the pointer towards the DateOffset stuff. I've posted a solution based on it.

Answer (score 1):

[pandas.DatetimeIndex.quarter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.quarter.html) Might also be useful.

And then you can use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to aggregate easily.

Answer (score 0):

Using Alex's pointer to the DateOffset functionality in Pandas I found a partial solution, as well as the datetime module:

```
import datetime
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *
now = datetime.datetime.now()
start_year = (now - BQuarterEnd(n=1) - (12 * MonthBegin())).to_datetime()
end_year = (now - BQuarterEnd(n=1) ).to_datetime()
df[start_year.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") : end_year.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")]
```